# Discord.JS Command Handler Subfolders Search

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a command handler for my discord bot that searches through the folder `./commands/` in which all the `.js` commands are listed. I want to clean up all of the commands and instead of having them all in the same folder, have them each on their own category folders. Now the problem is I have no idea how to make the bot search through sub directories of the `./commands/` folder to find each command in its own category folder. Below I have the code I use to search in `./commands/`. Any idea to make it search through every directory in `./commands/`?

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(`Loading a total of ${files.length} commands.`);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    console.log(`Loading Command: ${props.help.name} ✔`);
    client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
        props.conf.aliases.forEach(alias => {
      client.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
    });
  });
});
```

Edit:

This is the answer that jakemingolla helped me create:

```
function walk(dir, callback) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            console.log(`Loading a total of ${files.length} commands.`);
            var filepath = path.join(dir, file);
            fs.stat(filepath, function(err,stats) {
                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(filepath, callback);
                } else if (stats.isFile() && file.endsWith('.js')) {
                    let props = require(`./${filepath}`);
                    console.log(`Loading Command: ${props.help.name} ✔`);
                    client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
                    props.conf.aliases.forEach(alias => {
                    client.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
                  });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
walk(`./commands/`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a function to encapsulate repeated work!**

You're already halfway there - you have a function that can take a single directory and list the files within it. If you instead encounter a directory, repeat the process:

```
function walk(dir, callback) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            var filepath = path.join(dir, file);
            fs.stat(filepath, function(err,stats) {
                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(filepath, callback);
                } else if (stats.isFile() && file.endsWith('.js')) {
                    ... your logic here ...
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm attempting to figure out how to implement that into my code, but I get an error that states that `path` in `path.join` is not defined. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Ok I think I figured out how to fix the `path.join` by installing the npm module `path` and putting `const path = require("path");` at the top, but even if I do that It just wont work. No errors, but I tried putting a `console.log("True")` where you have the `...your logic here...` in the code and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Am I supposed to define `dir`? I honestly have no clue what to do.

Comment: Yep, you were right about `path`, I should have been more explicit with the `require()` call.

Comment: In this case `dir` is the argument to the `walk()` function - in order to call the function in your case, you would need to use a callback as well as provide the starting location: `walk('./commands', function(err, data) { ... })`

Comment: Where exactly would I put the `walk('./commands', function(err, data) { ... })`? Would I replace the `function walk(dir, callback){...}` or does it encompass all the code?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I really understand the question - the function *declaration* and *invocation* need to be separate in NodeJS

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show what you mean? I've added my edit to my question so you understand where I'm at.

Comment: Yep it looks like you're on track - is the edited question code still not working for you? If so, could you provide a specific error message?

Comment: The error I get is: `fs.js:897
  binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding, req);
TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer at Object.fs.readdir (fs.js:897:11)`

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now - the very first call to `walk()` is missing the starting position - to match your earlier example, try `walk(`./commands/`);

Comment: Alright! So that works, but then when I try to put in the rest of my code it gives me a throw error as it can't find the file in the test folder. I believe its due to the `let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);`. I've updated my code above.

Comment: Remember that the base directory might not be just `./commands` depending on how far you have recursed downed the directory tree. Instead, read the whole `filepath` name

Comment: YES! That seems to work just fine. Thank you for being so patient with me and being so thorough! You've saved my project.

Comment: Glad to have helped! (:

Answer (score 0):

This came from the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide).

```js
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}
```